# Run Docker for Windows without user login

Tags: windows, docker

I'm currently setting up a Windows 10 PC as a remote build agent which is intended to use Docker to automatically build applications. The problem is, that I have to connect to the machine at least once a day because Docker only starts on user login.

Is there a way to start Docker when Windows boots up, maybe with the task scheduler? Alternatively, is there a way to reliably prevent auto logout from Windows 10?